# image in tcpdf doesn't fit enterely the pdf

Tags: tcpdf

I can't define a background image on all the width of the pdf.
pdf is Letter US, format 'L' in parameters the size of the pdf is 279.4x215.9
the image size is 3300x2550px
for the print 27.94mm 21.59mm
dpi 300

the image take 80% of the width and height. I would want 100% with no marge, no padding, no footer, no header...

tcpdf 6.3.2
php 7.2

```
$diplomas->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 0);
    $diplomas->setCellPaddings(0,0,0,0);
    $diplomas->setCellMargins(0,0,0,0,false);
    $diplomas->setPrintHeader(false);
    $diplomas->SetFooterMargin(0);
    $diplomas->SetRightMargin(0);
    $diplomas->setPrintFooter(false);
    $diplomas->Image($img_file, 0, 0, 279, 216, '', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false);
    //$diplomas->writeHTMLCell(0, 0 , 0, 0, $fond, $border=0, $ln=1, $fill=0, $reseth=false, $align='', $autopadding=false);
    $diplomas->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, $x_nom, $y_nom, $nom, $border=0, $ln=1, $fill=0, $reseth=true, $align='', $autopadding=true);
    $diplomas->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, $x_ph, $y_ph, $ph, $border=0, $ln=1, $fill=0, $reseth=true, $align='', $autopadding=true);
    $diplomas->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, $x_date, $y_date, $date_diploma, $border=0, $ln=1, $fill=0, $reseth=true, $align='', $autopadding=true);
```

Do you have any idea, please?
Thanks
Chris